# error: no matching function for call to find_name

Tags: c++

```
list<SimpleList<int> *> listSLi;
list<SimpleList<double> *> listSLd;
list<SimpleList<string> *> listSLs;
```

This is main:

```
`int main() {
      cout << "Enter name of input file: ";
      string input_f;
      cin >> input_f;

  /*  cout << "Enter name of output file: ";
  string output_f;
  cin >> output_f;
  */
  ifstream input(input_f);
  //  ofstream output(output_f); // Make this a separate function

  string to_parse;
  vector<string> sep_words;
  while (getline(input, to_parse)) {
    //    cout << "PROCESSING COMMAND: " << to_parse << '\n';
    to_parse += '\n'; // getline removes the \n on each line
    sep_words = parse_line(to_parse);
    cpp(sep_words);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this is the SimpleList class. Derived classes are Stack and Queue.

```
template<typename T>
class SimpleList {
public:
  SimpleList();
  SimpleList(const string& n);
  virtual void push(T value) =0;
  virtual void pop() =0;
  void set_name(const string&);
  string get_name();
protected:
  void insert_front(T);
  void insert_back(T);
  void remove_front();
  // Should be protected:
  Node<T> first, last, temp;
  string name;
  int size;
};
```

sep_words will contain 2 or 3 strings.

```
void cpp(const vector<string>& single_words) {/////////////////////////
   if (single_words.size() == 2) { // pop
     switch(single_words[1][0]) {
     case 'i':
       if(is_name_in(single_words[1], 0) != true) {
         cout << "ERROR: This name does not exist!\n";
         return;
       }
       else if (is_list_empty(single_words[1], 0)) { // add == true for readability
         cout << "ERROR: This list is empty!\n";
           return;
       }
       else {
 312        find_name(single_words[1], 0)->pop();
       }
       break;
```

find_name(single_words[1], 0)->pop(); is the problem line

```
template<typename T>
SimpleList<T>* find_name(const string& nm, int which_type) { // Can do char which_type instead
  // 0 stands for integer 1 stands for double 2 stands for string
  switch(which_type) {
  case 0:
    for (list<SimpleList<int> *>::iterator it = listSLi.begin(); it != listSLi.end(); ++it) {
      if ((*it)->name == nm) { // Use get_name instead
        return *it;
      }
    }
    break;
  case 1:
    for (list<SimpleList<double> *>::iterator it = listSLd.begin(); it != listSLd.end(); ++it) {
      if ((*it)->name == nm) {
        return *it;
      }
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    for (list<SimpleList<string> *>::iterator it = listSLs.begin(); it != listSLs.end(); ++it) {
      if ((*it)->name == nm) {
        return *it;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void cpp(const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
main.cpp:312:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_name(const value_type&, int)’
   find_name(single_words[1], 0)->pop();
                               ^
main.cpp:312:31: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:272:16: note: template<class T> SimpleList<T>* find_name(const string&, int)
 SimpleList<T>* find_name(const string& nm, int which_type) { // Can do char which_type instead
                ^
main.cpp:272:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:312:31: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
   find_name(single_words[1], 0)->pop();
                               ^
```

Comment: Please mark line 312 in main.cpp in your question

Comment: Do you really need `find_name` to be a template function? Currently you're returning just `SimpleList<int> *` in any case.

Comment: I didnt show the whole function because it would be too long but I use doubles and strings in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

as the error message sais, the compiler cant deduce the type T in your template.

```
template<typename T>
SimpleList<T>* find_name(const string& nm, int which_type); ....
```

Here the type T is the parameter to the function. But the compiler can't know which type you mean, since it does not appear in the arguments.

```
 const string& nm, int which_type // what shall be T?
```

So maybe instead of `string` you want T here, or supply the type directly like `find_name<string>(...)`

I did not understand the whole purpose, but that adresses the error :)

Enhancement:

the flag `which_type` is probably unnecessary as well, since dispatching can be done on the overload level. See tagging (e.g. iterator_tags in the stl) and overloading in general.